# Why SPS and PPS sents in different chunk stream id?

Tags: video, stream, h.264, rtmp, flv

I'm working with RTMP. I need to write a program that captures  RTMP packets, parse it and save  RTMP video in flv container. For this purpose i need SPS and PPS which sent in the stream begin. But this data may sent in different streams. For examle:

1. SPS and PPS sent in stream 6 and video data sent in stream 7.
2. SPS,PPS and video data comes in stream 7.

How do I know  which stream belongs  to SPS and PPS if i have 3 video streams and only 1 stream which contain SPS and PPS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"How do I know which stream belongs to SPS and PPS if i have 3 video streams and only 1 stream which contain SPS and PPS?"*

SPS and PPS are for the setting up the MPEG decoder only. Once it's setup to handle one stream, you can change to decoding other streams in file without a need for any new SPS & PPS.

Unless the 3 streams are drastically different (ie: each with different picture size & own different frame rates, etc). In such a case then you would need new SPS & PPS.

Answer (score 1):

As I have noticed in my case, the first video frame what we get in RTMP is having those two values. When you are storing it as a single FLV file, you can just have it as a first frame.

But in case you want to split it into smaller files of shorter intervals—e.g., for streaming using DASH—then you need to paste that first frame in every split file you create. That can be automatically done with the help of `ffmpeg`. In that case, if you want to include the code with in that RTMP Client, you can follow this. Otherwise you may not be able to play the split files except for first one.

As I mentioned above, the first frame converted to hex string:

```
17 - It represents 1 - Keyframe
                   7 - H.264 
00 00 00 00 01 64 00 28 ff e1 00 - ?  
1a - Size of the SPS 
67 64 00 28 ac d9 40 78 02 27 e5 84 00 00 03 00 04 00 00 03 00 f2 3c 60 c6 58 - SPS
01 - According to AMF0 01 represent number
00 04 - Size of PPS
68 ef bc bc - PPS
```

(I’m not sure what the hexadecimals followed by the `- ?` represent. If anyone can fill that part in, feel free to comment and I’ll update my answer.)

To understand what is SPS in detailed: [Refer Here](https://www.cardinalpeak.com/the-h-264-sequence-parameter-set/)

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the community. I appreciate it. With the uncertainty over the one line of HEX, I didn’t want this to be mistaken as a follow-up question, so I edited that portion to help clarify that it is an ancillary question to your overall response. If I misunderstood, do let me know.